# Estimating WCET of a task on Linux

Tags: linux, algorithm, performance, perf

I want to ***approximate*** the Worst Case Execution Time (WCET) for a set of tasks on linux. Most professional tools are either expensive (1000s $), or don't support my processor architecture.

Since, I don't need a tight bound, my line of thought is that I :

1. disable frequency scaling
2. disbale unnecesary background services and tasks
3. set the program affinity to run on a specified core
4. run the program for 50,000 times with various inputs
5. Profiling it and storing the total number of cycles it had completed to
   execute.
6. Given the largest clock cycle count and knowing the core frequency, I can get an estimate

   Is this is a sound **Practical** approach?

Secondly, to account for interference from other tasks,  I will run the whole task set (40) tasks in parallel with each randomly assigned a core and do the same thing for 50,000 times.

Once I get the estimate, a 10% safe margin will be added to account for unforseeble interference and untested path. This 10% margin has been suggested in the paper "Approximation of Worst Case Execution time in Preepmtive Multitasking Systems" by Corti, Brega and Gross

Answer (score 0):

Some comments:

1) Even attempting to compute worst case bounds in this way means making assumptions that there aren't uncommon inputs that cause tasks to take much more or even much less time. An extreme example would be a bug that causes one of the tasks to go into an infinite loop, or that causes the whole thing to deadlock. You need something like a code review to establish that the time taken will always be pretty much the same, regardless of input.

2) It is possible that the input data does influence the time taken to some extent. Even if this isn't apparent to you, it could happen because of the details of the implementation of some library function that you call. So you need to run your tests on a representative selection of real life data.

3) When you have got your 50K test results, I would draw some sort of probability plot - see e.g. http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/normprpl.htm and links off it. I would be looking for isolated points that show that in a few cases some runs were suspiciously slow or suspiciously fast, because the code review from (1) said there shouldn't be runs like this. I would also want to check that adding 10% to the maximum seen takes me a good distance away from the points I have plotted. You could also plot time taken against different parameters from the input data to check that there wasn't any pattern there.

4) If you want to try a very sophisticated approach, you could try fitting a statistical distribution to the values you have found - see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_Pareto_distribution. But plotting the data and looking at it is probably the most important thing to do.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I am aware of the points 1 and 2 you mentioned. Now, referring to the paper "WCET Analysis /methods: Pitfalls and Challenges on their Trustworthiness", 2015. They do mention the difficulties we have to this day when estimating WCET for industrial and real-life workloads especially where safety is concerned. I do know that measurment alone is not enough and I need to couple that with some statistical tool. It seems Extreme Value Theorem has been tested for WCET and it has merit. My question was based on the validity of my approach, if it is missing any steps or has faults